# What role does the keystore files play for SSL?

Tags: servlets, security, keystore

Being completely  , new to SSL I finally managed to get my application running using https:

In the tomcat server I added

```
    <Connector port="8443"
    maxThreads="150" minSpareThreads="25" maxSpareThreads="75"
enableLookups="true" disableUploadTimeout="true"
acceptCount="100" debug="0" scheme="https" secure="true"
    clientAuth="false" sslProtocol="TLS"
    keystoreFile="c:/keystore.key"
    keystorePass="mypassword" 
    SSLEnabled="true" />
```

and in my application i added

```
 <user-data-constraint>
          <transport-guarantee>CONFIDENTIAL</transport-guarantee> 
 </user-data-constraint>
```

Now my question is even if I delete the keystore file from c:\ which i generated using :

```
keytool -genkey -alias tomcat -keypass pass -keystore keystore.key -storepass pass
```

My application still runs in https ? What difference does it make if i have the file or not ? I couldnt really tell ?

Comment: Have you restarted Tomcat since you deleted the file?

Comment: I realized that after restarting the server .. it never worked.

Comment: If you've deleted that file you're just going to have to rebuild it. It's your private key, it's precious, try not to lose it again. Soon you will want to generate a CSR from it to get your certificate signed by a CA.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Private keys are used in the authentication phase of the SSL handshake, to sign the certificate you provided. The peer verifies the signature via the certificate's public key. This proves that you own the certificate, because only you can sign it with the private key corresponding to its public key, because only you have the private key, because it's private. This is part of establishing your identity, i.e. authentication.

An SSL client only needs a private key, certificate, keystore etc., if the server needs or wants client authentication.

The server's private key is also used in the initial phase of generating the shared secret, which in turn is used to generate the session keys for the session. Data is encrypted by the session key.